# Finding an upper bound using the Estimation Lemma for this expression

Tags: complex-analysis

Is my reasoning correct?

> Without actually evaluating the integral, show that:
>
> $$I = \int_\phi \frac{1}{1+z^2} \leq\frac{3\pi}{16}$$
>   $\text{Where } \phi \text{ is the circular arc connecting }3 \text{ to } 3i$

Here's what I tried: *Let L($\phi$) denote the length of the arc*

$$L|\phi(t)| = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}|3ie^{it}|dt = \frac{3\pi}{2}$$

Now it remains to find:
$$inf\{|1 + (3e^{it})^2|,\text{ where t}\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\}$$
Expanding $|1 + (3e^{it})^2|$ gives me the expression:
$$|1 + (3e^{it})^2| = \sqrt{(1 + 9\cos(2t))^2 + (9\sin(2t))^2}
=\sqrt{82 + 18\cos(2t)}$$

Minimising this in the domain of t, we get, for t = $\frac{\pi}{2}$:
$$inf\{|1 + (3e^{it})^2|,\text{ where t}\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\} = \sqrt{64} = 8$$

Hence by the Estimating Lemma, we have:
$$I \leq \frac{3\pi}{16}$$

Comment: Yes this is valid, but you can be more concise. You shouldn't need an integral to compute the arc-length of a quarter-circle. Also if $|z|=3$, then $|1+z^2|\ge|z^2|-1=8$ from the triangle inequality.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Neat! Did not occur to me to use the triangle equality!